# Mapping in a string

Tags: python

I'm required to use a string to in converting RNA to Proteins given a dictionary of such kay value pairs. The start of making the protein would require the "AUG" to be detected in the string and the end will require "UAA", "UAG" and "UGA" to be detected to stop the process.

For example, translate("AUGUAA") would give 'M_' and translate("AGAGAUGCCCUGAGGG") would give 'MP_' when accessing the key,value pairs in the dictionary called codon2amino.

```
    def get_mapping(csvfilename):
        mapping = read_csv(csvfilename)
        return dict(map(lambda x : (x[0],x[3]),mapping))
```

This is what I've tried but I'm stuck as to where to go from here:

```
    def translate(rna_strand):
         codon2amino = get_mapping("codon_mapping.csv")
         start_codon = "AUG"
         start_index = rna_strand.find(start_codon)
         stop_codons = ["UAA", "UAG", "UGA"]
         acid_list=[]
         if start_codon and "UAA" not in rna_strand:
             return None
         elif start_codon and "UAG" not in rna_strand:
             return None
         elif start_codon and "UGA" not in rna_strand:
             return None
         else:
               codons = [rna_strand[i:i+3] for i in range(start_index+3, len(rna_strand), 3)]
         for codon in codons:
             if codon in stop_codons:
                  break
 
         acid_list.append(codon2amino[codon])
      amino_acid = ''.join(amino_list) + "_"
      return amino_acid
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Your question, in its current state, is hard to understand so please add ample amounts of sample inputs and expected outputs... that way we will be able to help you :)

Comment: Hi its a little bit hard because the get_mapping function is from a csv file with rows with headers codon and amino acid. But what codon2amino returns would be a dictionary containing (codon:amino acid).

Comment: @Yatin I've really tried to add as much info as i can as Ive only been given 2 test cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumming each codon is 3 characters long, you could retrieve each codon from the `rna_strand` with:

```py
codons = [rna_strand[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(rna_strand), 3)]
```

Then you can use the mapping to map each codon to its amino with:

```py
amino_list = [codon2amino[codon] for codon in codons]
```

And lastly, you can combine them to form the amino acid with:

```py
amino_acid = ''.join(amino_list)
```

In one line, it would look like:

```py
amino_acid = ''.join([codon2amino[rna_strand[i:i+3]] for i in range(0, len(rna_strand), 3)])
```

But as @Yatin mentioned, more details about the inputs/outputs and what the mapping `codon2amino` looks like.

**Edit:**
You can first search for the start codon with:

```py
start_codon = "AUG"
start_idx = rna_strand.find(start_codon)
```

Then, split the rest into codons:

```py
codons = [rna_strand[i:i+3] for i in range(start_idx, len(rna_strand), 3)]
```

And then you can just iterate over them until you hit an end codon:

```py
stop_codons = {"UAA", "UAG", "UGA"}
amino_list = []
for codon in codons:
  # We've hit a stop codon, so we halt
  if codon in stop_codons:
    break
  if codon not in codon2amino:
    print("Invalid codon found", codon)
    break
  amino_list.append(codon2amino[codon])
amino_acid = ''.join(amino_list) + "_"
```

Comment: Hi! the mapping function would return a tuple of tuples (Codon,aminoacid) but automatically splitting it into 3 wont really work since for example AGAGAUGCCCUGAGGG if you split it into 3 automatically it would be AGA GAU UGC and so on but there is a AUG present. In other words if there in an AUG present that would be the first codon to start from if not the chain would not be valid and will return None. Additionally, it would have to be able to scan for the stop codons to know when to stop the conversion and return  a _ at the end. I hope this additional details help!

Comment: The mapping codon2amino returns a dictionary with key = codon and value = amino acid. What translate has to do is scan for the first instance of AUG and then start splitting it into threes from there until it detects the first instance of a stop codon where the amino acid chain will end with a _

Comment: @BryanTan I updated my answer to fit your requirements. I haven't tested/ran the code, but the general idea is there. Hope that helps!

Comment: hi! i tried using your code with some tweaks at the second if statement for codon not in codon2amino (removed). I think the break statement might be causing the entire thing to be not translated at all

Comment: Sounds good! Did that work? If so, don't forget to mark this as the correct answer :)

Comment: Hi turns out it doenst work just yet because what comes out is emtpy haha! ive edited my solution above but its still not right

Comment: I was thinking somewhere along the lines of if there is a stop codon detected  the return would be what was produced before with an addition of a _

Comment: Hi, I think the fix is to add `3` to `start_idx`:  `codons = [rna_strand[i:i+3] for i in range(start_idx + 3, len(rna_strand), 3)]`, and leave the break statement in. The reason why it failed was because without the `+3`, we are including the start codon in the codon list which itself doesn't have a matching amino name which is why the `break` returned early.

Comment: Hi i tried the fix as shown in my edit above but it still returns none haha.

Comment: Can you give me details on the output? What codons are in `codons` before the loop?

Comment: Hi the fix works! But theres one more private test case that if there is no stop codon present the chain would also return None but when i use the additional conditon to check if stop codons are present the chain would return None

Comment: So the conditions to check for would be if it has a start codon and stop codon

Answer (score 0):

You can devide you RNA code to list of codons using `textwrap`:

```
import textwrap
textwrap.wrap("AUGUAA", 3) # returns ["AUG", "UAA"]
```

Now you can easly iterate over them.

Comment: Hello! The code has to scan for the first AUG present meaning that if there is no AUG present in the string, it would be invalid and I would return none.